# 2D vectors in java getting vague output in java

Tags: java, mysql, vector

i am getting some table data from mysql database, and storing that in vectors(2D)
but when i print that vector, i am not getting desired output.

CODE:

```
package vectortrial;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Vectortrial {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Vector<Vector<String>> empvector = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
        Vector<String> emp = new Vector<String>();
        String a;
        String b;

        try{  
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
                Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/alarm","root","xyz123");  
                 Statement stmt= con.createStatement();  
                 ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from current");  
                while(rs.next())  
                {   a = rs.getString(1);
                    b = rs.getString(2);
                    emp.add(a);
                    emp.add(b);
                System.out.println(a+"  "+b);

                empvector.add(emp);
                }
                 con.close();  
            }catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}  
            System.out.println(empvector);



    }
}
```

Output that i am getting:

```
// output data from database

1     abc    
2     def

[[1,abc,2,def],[1,abc,2,def]]    //vector value
```

Actual output that i was expecting:

```
[[1,abc],[2,def]]
```

Can some one pour some insights where i went wrong or tell me some concept that i have applied wrongly.

Comment: you have to create `emp = new Vector..` inside the loop

Comment: thank you, it worked like a charm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@FastSnail beat me to the answer by a few seconds (his screen name is very accurate), but your loop iterating over the result set should look like this:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    a = rs.getString(1);
    b = rs.getString(2);
    // create a new vector corresponding to each record in the result set
    emp = new Vector<String>();
    emp.add(a);
    emp.add(b);
    System.out.println(a + "  " + b);

    empvector.add(emp);
}
```

Your original code keeps recycling the same intermediate vector, hence your apparent result set will seem to keep adding each record.